# All Thymeleaf fragments in one .html file, choose one to use

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and suppose I have a file header.html:

```
<head th:fragment="fragA">...</head>

<head th:fragment="fragB">...</head>

<head th:fragment="fragC">...</head>
```

And I want to take header fragA into the file index.html:

```
<html>
   <head th:replace="fragA">...</head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Am I able to do this.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried and index.html had all the frag A,B,C

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the file and fragment:

```xml
<html>
   <head th:replace="header :: fragA">...</head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

(I am assuming you are doing this in the context of Spring: You may need to use header.html depending on your resolver and default template suffix setting.)